# (Laravel4) Update row in table?

Tags: database, laravel

I managed to update a row in my table. But instead of just adding a new value, I want to do use some math with it.

So if the value of my table is '10'. I want to be able to do +2 so it turns out 12.

This is what I got now:

```
public function postDeposit() {
        $amount = Input::get('deposit');
        DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->update(array('bank' => $amount));

}
```

I have tried like the following

```
'bank', '+', $amount
```

But apparently is doesn't work like that and I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i have found the answer myself.^^

**To add something:**

```
DB::table('users')->increment('rowName', 5);
```

**To remove**

```
DB::table('users')->decrement('rowName', 3);
```

Comment: `Sorry, i have found the answer myself.^^`, Then never try to find any answer by yourself, stay happy :-)